# Parameter of Python function call is reserved word in Julia

Tags: julia, pycall

I am playing around with the yfinance package (https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) to learn Julia and ran into an issue with a parameter that is also a reserved word in Julia.

```
using PyCall

y = pyimport("yfinance")
data = y.download("SPY AAPL", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30") # does not work
#data = y.download("SPY", start="2018-01-01")   #works
```

Error message:

```
LoadError: syntax: unexpected "end"
in expression starting at C:\Users\user\Github\julia\using_python.jl:6
top-level scope at using_python.jl:6
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interpolating a dictionary should work:

```
data = y.download("SPY AAPL"; Dict(:start => "2017-01-01", :end => "2017-04-30")...)
```